# Please help stuck on this UML diagram

Tags: java

```
UML:
-name: String
-playerId: int
-scores: int[]
-bestScore: int
-numberOfPlayers: int
<< constructors>>
+Player()
+Player(name: String)
<< set methods>>
+setName(name: String):void
+setScores(score: int[]):void
<< get methods >>
+getPlayerId():int
+getName():String
+getScores():int[]
+getBestScore(): int
+calculateAverage(): double
<< helper methods >>
-calculateBestScore(): void
```

- The constructors will increment the static variable numberOfPlayers and then assign the value
  of numberOfPlayers to the playerId.
- The calculateAverage() public method determines the average score for a player from the
  data stored in the scores array.
- The getBestScore() method calls the calculateBestScore() private helper method to
  determines the highest score achieved so far by a player.

Any ideas how should i set the numberOfPlayers assign value to playerId ?
And how to I do the calculateAverage and calculateBestScore methods ?

My code at the moment is:

```
    //Class declaration of Player class
    public class Player
    {
        /*--------------- Data Fields --------------------------------------
        Attributes of the class
        */
        private String name;
        private int playerId;
        private int bestScore;
        private int numberOfPlayers;
        private int scores;
        /* -------------- CONSTRUCTOR --------------------------------------
        */
        public Player(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.numberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayers + 1;
            this.playerId = this.numberOfPlayers;
        }
        //Create set method for setName
        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        //Create set method for setScores
        public void setScore(int score)
        {
            scores = score;
        }
        //Create get method for getPlayerId
        public int getPlayerId()
        {
            return playerId;
        }

        //Create get method for getName
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        //Create get method for getScores
        public int getScores()
        {
            return scores;
        }
        //Create get method for getBestScore
        public int getBestScore()
        {
        return bestScore;
        }
        //Create get method for calcualteAverage
        public double calculateAverage()
        {
        }
        }
```

Comment: Please choose a better title: imagine someone is solving similar problem. The title should let him know if this question helps him or not.

Comment: Where is the scores array? And calculating the average is very simple and straight forward same with the best score.

Comment: Yes this was my first post so did not have any idea how to post the question. I will make the title more specific next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The constructors will increment the static variable numberOfPlayers and then assign the value of numberOfPlayers to the playerId

Give your variable the `static` identifier, and also initialize it:

```
private static int numberOfPlayers = 0;
```

Every time you create a new Player class, increment it by 1:

```
public Person() {
    numberOfPlayers++;
}
```

You'll need a method to expose the value of numberOfPlayers, and make it `static` so any Player class can call it:

```
public static int getNumPlayers() {
    return numberOfPlayers;
}
```

Test it's a valid approach as such:

```
Person a = new Person();
Person b = new Person();
Person c = new Person();

System.out.println(c.getNumPlayers()); //will be 3 based on the above
```

Regarding calculation of scores, your `getScores` and `setScore` methods will be problematic. First, `getScores` implies you must return more than one score. Second, `setScore` has me wondering how many times you must do this for one player, and where will you store the values as they grow in a collection of scores? I feel it will be too ambitious for me to guess at the different approaches that may satisfy your need. If this is a school assignment, check with your instructor. I'll share this one approach that uses the `ArrayList` data structure:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public Person() {

}

public void setScore(int score) {
    scores.add(score);
}
```

To get the best score - [how to get maximum value from the List/ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304767/how-to-get-maximum-value-from-the-list-arraylist)

To get the average score - [Calculating average of an array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791568/calculating-average-of-an-array-list)

Comment: Thanks for that @ThisClark. The second part was to create an executable application that will ask the user to guess a number between 1-20. Each player is asked to play the game five times, so five scores are stored for each player. I will try and do this myself from now on I was really just stuck on that numberOfPlayers part. Once again big thanks

Comment: Any ideas what my get Method should be like for getScores. I have set scores into private ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>(); and setScore as you mentioned above but I am getting errors on getScore(). public int getScores()
 {
  return scores;
 }

Comment: @AnthonyGalpo Your method is defined as `public int getScores()` but my sample declared the scores variable as `private ArrayList<Integer> scores` therefore you need to redefine your method as `public ArrayList<Integer> getScores()` then it should work. In this case, the return type `ArrayList<Integer>` of your method simply needs to match the thing you are returning.

Comment: Thank you so much I figured it out last night myself.