# Finding the mean of all integers in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, average

I am currently making a simulator for fake basketball players but am currently stuck on **finding the mean** of all of the numbers in the `ArrayList`.

I know how to add all of the values up but when ever I try to make a counter variable to divide the list or use `list.getSize()`, none of them work.

Hopefully this makes sense to you, I am happy to explain the problem in more detail.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Application {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField pst;
    private JTextField pg;
    private JTextField sg;
    private JTextField pf;
    private JTextField C;
    private JTextField sf;
    private JTextField txtPlayerName;
    private JTextField ED;
    private JTextField CJ;
    private JTextField SB;
    private JTextField SW;
    private JTextField JO;
    private JTextField num;
    private JTextField edNum;
    private JTextField cjNum;
    private JTextField sbNum;
    private JTextField swNum;
    private JTextField joNum;
    private JTextField ppg;
    private JTextField ppgED;
    private JTextField ppgCJ;
    private JTextField ppgSB;
    private JTextField ppgJO;
    private JTextField ppgSW;
    private JButton btnPlay;
    private List<Integer> ppgList;
    private int sum;
    private int counter;

    // Launch the application.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Application window = new Application();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Application() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        initComponenets();
        createEvents();
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Contains all of the code for creating events
    private void createEvents() {

    }
    //Contains all of the code for creating and initializing components
    private void initComponenets() {

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Frame
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Title");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 801, 450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Title
        JTextPane title = new JTextPane();
        title.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        title.setEditable(false);
        title.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        title.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        title.setBounds(237, 11, 296, 50);
        title.setText("   Basketball Simulation Game");
        frame.getContentPane().add(title);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Position TextBox
        pst = new JTextField();
        pst.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        pst.setEditable(false);
        pst.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        pst.setText("PST");
        pst.setBounds(10, 64, 50, 35);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pst);
        pst.setColumns(10);

        pg = new JTextField();
        pg.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        pg.setText("PG");
        pg.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        pg.setEditable(false);
        pg.setColumns(10);
        pg.setBounds(10, 99, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pg);

        sg = new JTextField();
        sg.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        sg.setText("SG");
        sg.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        sg.setEditable(false);
        sg.setColumns(10);
        sg.setBounds(10, 148, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(sg);

        sf = new JTextField();
        sf.setText("SF");
        sf.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        sf.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        sf.setEditable(false);
        sf.setColumns(10);
        sf.setBounds(10, 196, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(sf);

        pf = new JTextField();
        pf.setText("PF");
        pf.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        pf.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        pf.setEditable(false);
        pf.setColumns(10);
        pf.setBounds(10, 242, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pf);

        C = new JTextField();
        C.setText("C");
        C.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        C.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        C.setEditable(false);
        C.setColumns(10);
        C.setBounds(10, 291, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(C);


        /////////////////////////////////////////////// PlayerName
        txtPlayerName = new JTextField();
        txtPlayerName.setText("Player Name");
        txtPlayerName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtPlayerName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        txtPlayerName.setEditable(false);
        txtPlayerName.setColumns(10);
        txtPlayerName.setBounds(59, 64, 95, 35);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtPlayerName);

        ED = new JTextField();
        ED.setText("ED");
        ED.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ED.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        ED.setEditable(false);
        ED.setColumns(10);
        ED.setBounds(59, 99, 95, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ED);

        CJ = new JTextField();
        CJ.setText("CJ");
        CJ.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        CJ.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        CJ.setEditable(false);
        CJ.setColumns(10);
        CJ.setBounds(59, 148, 95, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(CJ);

        SB = new JTextField();
        SB.setText("SB");
        SB.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        SB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        SB.setEditable(false);
        SB.setColumns(10);
        SB.setBounds(59, 196, 95, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(SB);

        SW = new JTextField();
        SW.setText("Swanigan");
        SW.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        SW.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        SW.setEditable(false);
        SW.setColumns(10);
        SW.setBounds(59, 245, 95, 47);
        frame.getContentPane().add(SW);

        JO = new JTextField();
        JO.setText("Jordan");
        JO.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JO.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        JO.setEditable(false);
        JO.setColumns(10);
        JO.setBounds(59, 291, 95, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(JO);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////Numbers
        num = new JTextField();
        num.setText("#");
        num.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        num.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        num.setEditable(false);
        num.setColumns(10);
        num.setBounds(153, 64, 50, 35);
        frame.getContentPane().add(num);

        edNum = new JTextField();
        edNum.setText("0");
        edNum.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        edNum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        edNum.setEditable(false);
        edNum.setColumns(10);
        edNum.setBounds(153, 99, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(edNum);

        cjNum = new JTextField();
        cjNum.setText("3");
        cjNum.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        cjNum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        cjNum.setEditable(false);
        cjNum.setColumns(10);
        cjNum.setBounds(153, 148, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(cjNum);

        sbNum = new JTextField();
        sbNum.setText("24");
        sbNum.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        sbNum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        sbNum.setEditable(false);
        sbNum.setColumns(10);
        sbNum.setBounds(153, 196, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(sbNum);

        swNum = new JTextField();
        swNum.setText("8");
        swNum.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        swNum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        swNum.setEditable(false);
        swNum.setColumns(10);
        swNum.setBounds(153, 245, 50, 47);
        frame.getContentPane().add(swNum);

        joNum = new JTextField();
        joNum.setText("23");
        joNum.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        joNum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        joNum.setEditable(false);
        joNum.setColumns(10);
        joNum.setBounds(153, 291, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(joNum);

        //////////////////////////////////Points per game
        ppg = new JTextField();
        ppg.setText("PPG");
        ppg.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ppg.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        ppg.setEditable(false);
        ppg.setColumns(10);
        ppg.setBounds(201, 64, 50, 35);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ppg);

        ppgED = new JTextField();
        ppgED.setText("0.0");
        ppgED.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ppgED.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        ppgED.setEditable(false);
        ppgED.setColumns(10);
        ppgED.setBounds(201, 99, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ppgED);

        ppgCJ = new JTextField();
        ppgCJ.setText("0.0");
        ppgCJ.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ppgCJ.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        ppgCJ.setEditable(false);
        ppgCJ.setColumns(10);
        ppgCJ.setBounds(201, 148, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ppgCJ);

        ppgSB = new JTextField();
        ppgSB.setText("0.0");
        ppgSB.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ppgSB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        ppgSB.setEditable(false);
        ppgSB.setColumns(10);
        ppgSB.setBounds(201, 196, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ppgSB);

        ppgJO = new JTextField();
        ppgJO.setText("0.0");
        ppgJO.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ppgJO.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        ppgJO.setEditable(false);
        ppgJO.setColumns(10);
        ppgJO.setBounds(201, 291, 50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ppgJO);

        ppgSW = new JTextField();
        ppgSW.setText("0.0");
        ppgSW.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ppgSW.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        ppgSW.setEditable(false);
        ppgSW.setColumns(10);
        ppgSW.setBounds(201, 245, 50, 47);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ppgSW);

        ////////////////////////////////////////Play JButton
        btnPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
        btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getPPG(33, ppgED);
            }
        });
        btnPlay.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        btnPlay.setBounds(304, 344, 160, 56);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnPlay);




    }

    public void getPPG(int num, JTextField box){

        Random rand = new Random();
        String text;
        ppgList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int xy = 0; xy < 1; xy++){

            num = num + rand.nextInt(10);
            ppgList.add(num);

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < ppgList.size(); i++)
        {
            counter++;
            sum = sum + ppgList.get(i) / counter;
        }
        Integer.toString(sum);
        text = String.valueOf(sum);
        box.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way the code that doesn't work is in the getPPG() method on the bottom of the page

Comment: Way too much, no problem description.

Comment: HINT: the mean (also called "average") of _n_ numbers is the sum of all those numbers divided by _n_.

Comment: Getting the average of a list of numbers has ***nothing*** to do with Swing. Also, don't inflict 'code dumps' on us. Prepare and post a [mcve] that is **specific* to the problem (which could be done using a command line app. that has a list of numbers written in or generated by the code). Removed Swing tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating average of an array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791568/calculating-average-of-an-array-list)

Comment: Kevin Anderson I think I know what mean is by the way, your comment is irrelevant. And Andrew Thompson why did you even comment about that and it technically is swing but not a swing issue.

Comment: @Zabuza yeah buddy that's what I did down there and I really like the smart ass response by the way :D

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach adds an item divided by the current counter which is not correct. Take a look at the following example:

```
values:      1, 2, 3, 4, 5
average:     3

your result:   1/1 + 2/2 + 3/3 + 4/4 + 5/5
             = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
             = 5
```

The correct approach first computes the overall sum of all values and then divides by the amount of items.

```
correct:  (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 5
         = 15 / 5
         = 3
```

Or alternatively you could apply the **distributive property** of division and addition and obtain the equivalent expression:

```
1/5 + 2/5 + 3/5 + 4/5 + 5/5
```

However you should stay as long as possible at `int` to avoid precision problems and exploit the heavy integer optimizations of the JVM.

---

You could either compute the average on your own or simply use methods from the Java library like `IntStream#average`:

```
// Setup the list
Random rnd = new Random();
int amount = 1_000;
int valueUpperBound = 10;

ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
    values.add(rnd.nextInt(valueUpperBound));
}

// Compute the average
double avg = values.stream()
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .average()
    .getAsDouble();
```

The code uses your list as source for a stream, then it maps each value `Integer` to an `int` using the `Integer#intValue` method in order to obtain an `IntStream` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)). This class offers methods like `IntStream#average` which returns an `OptionalDouble` and the `OptionalDouble#getAsDouble` method returns the result (for details take a look at the documentation).

---

A correct by-hand average computation looks like (from here: [SO/a/10791597/2411243](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791597/2411243)):

```
private double calculateAverage(List<Integer> values) {
    Integer sum = 0;
    if(!values.isEmpty()) {
        for (Integer value : values) {
            sum += value;
        }
        return sum.doubleValue() / values.size();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the actual average call, no?